# show and hide textboxes based on the value in textbox. angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a text box and two buttons on a page. The textbox recieves data from the database. If the textbox has  a value I want to show `Turn Off` and hide the other.  If the textbox doesn't have a value I want show `Turn On` and hide the other.

Because I am binding the textbox to sessionStorage.clientId, `null` gets displayed in the textbox if there is no data for the corresponding field in database. And also always `Turn On` button only showsup.  what am i doing wrong.

Here is the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ezbZDFzv9iA3STBR3aAS?p=preview)

Comment: I guess, null is treated as string("null") instead of null value. Your plunker works fine but does not reflect your question. Please update your plunker.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, you should stick with that

```
  $scope.ssclientID = {
     code: 'CS123BD'
   }
```

and use `$scope.ssclientID.code` in ng-model and everything should work just fine

Answer (score 1):

**It works**

Everything works fine, there is nothing wrong with your code. Plunker fails to load Angular, other than that it's OK. Here is the copy/paste to codepen.io :
http://codepen.io/ssh33/pen/jqRmdb?editors=1010

I added checks for an empty string `''` for giggles, but everything else is yours.